# Retrieve a given selection based on a linked table field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm beginner at Symfony (use SF5).  have a comments table, inside which is a filmId column, which is of type relation with the primary id of, you can imagine, the film table. For the moment I get a film on a page according to its id, and get all the comments, no matter the id of the film:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/film/{id}", name="film")
 */
public function film(FilmRepository $repo, CommentRepository $comRepo, EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $req, $id)
{
 $film = $repo->find($id);

 $comments = $comRepo->findAll();
 dump($comments);



 return $this->render('film/film.html.twig', [
     'controller_name' => 'FilmController',
     'film' => $film,
     'comments' => $comments
 ]);
}
```

I *dump()* $comments to find out a little more. It returns to me that filmId is of type PersistentCollection. I would like to retrieve the comments specific to each film according to filmId.

I tried to retrieve them by a *$comments = $comRepo-> findBy($id)* (since the id of the film I get in GET is what I want for the filmId), it gives me a nice *unrecognized field* error.

Following the documentation, I tried to create a custom query like this:

```php
//CommentRepository
public function findAllWithFilmId($filmId) 
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT c
            FROM App\Entity\Comment c
            WHERE c.filmId = :filmId'
        )->setParameter('filmId', $filmId);

        return $query->getResult();
    }
//FilmController
 $filmId = $id;
 $comments = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Comment::class)
    ->findAllWithFilmId($filmId);
```

But I get the following error:

*[Semantical Error] line 0, col 67 near 'filmId =: fi': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.*

What's wrong ? When is filmId defined as :fi? And how to create a correct request according to the filmId?

Comment: If the table name is aliased as c, is it by intent having a field called c?

Comment: No, not particularly, i understand that symfony makes aliases with the first letter of the entities, and i took example on the methods of documentation and those commented directly in the repository.

Comment: I'd suggest you rather use the [Query Builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html) to create the query. It should eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error `$comments = $comRepo-> findBy($id)` is beacuse when calling `findBy` you need to send an array. [Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

In your case, you want to find by Id so it should be as following:

```
$comments = $comRepo->findBy(array('id' => $id));
```

Also you can call `findById` which expects only the id parameter.

```
$comments = $comRepo->findById($id);
```

Note: as @El_Vanja said, you can use the QueryBuilder, but IMO it is unnecesary for a simple query llike this one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get comments according to their id, except that I would like to get all comments according to their filmId, a field linked to the primary id of film

Comment: If your attribute is called filmId, for example, just changing it for findBy(array('filmId' => $filmId)), or using findByFilmId($filmId) will work.

Comment: Checkt this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851608/request-a-linked-field-in-symfony in the comments.

Comment: I would say, the main goal of using ORM is not to build queries by yourself.

Comment: Yes, probably the best choice would be to change the entity to get the comments from the film itself.