# Request a linked field in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a page that displays information about a movie. I recover in GET the id of the film. What I would like to do is retrieve the comments for each film (there is a filmId column in my table linked to the primary id of the film table)

```php
   /**
     * @Route("/user/film/{id}", name="film")
     */
    public function film(FilmRepository $repo, CommentRepository $comRepo, EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $req, $id)
    {
        $film = $repo->find($id);

        $comments = $comRepo->findBy(array('id' => $id));





        return $this->render('film/film.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'FilmController',
            'film' => $film,
            'comments' => $comments
        ]);
    }
```

when I make a *$comments = $comRepo->findBy(array('id' => $id));* I get some comments, but based on their id and **NOT** the film id (the comment with id 1 will be displayed on the film with id 1, but for example a comment with id 4 and the filmId a 1 will not appear on film 1, but on the film with id 4)

I tried to access the filmId field by simply making a *$comments = $comRepo->findBy(array ('filmId' => $ id));* but i get the error :

***An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.content AS content_2, t0.created_at AS created_at_3, t0.author_id AS author_id_4 FROM comment t0 WHERE comment_film.film_id = ?' with params ["1"]:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comment_film.film_id' in 'where clause'***

I tried a personalized request with, in my Comment repository:

```php
public function findAllWithFilmId($filmId) 
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT c
            FROM App\Entity\Comment c
            WHERE c.filmId = :filmId'
        )->setParameter('filmId', $filmId);

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work..

**Where do I go to make a request like this ?**
How to modify the request, which seems erroneous, **from symfony** without disorganizing everything? or is there a better method to correct the problem?

This is my Comment Entity

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Film;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Film", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $filmId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;



    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?User
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(?User $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getFilmId(): ?Film
    {
        return $this->filmId;
    }

    public function setFilmId(?Film $filmId): self 
    {
        $this->filmId = $filmId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I think it is possible that the error comes from **annotations**, because starting on symfony during the make: entity, I defined types relations which I corrected later in phpmyadmin, but not the code. For example we can see that filmId is in ManyToMany, but I think it should be in OneToOne (FilmId can only have one id and an id can only correspond to one filmId), but I'm afraid that if I change certain things it **breaks everything**.

Comment: Your code seems ok. You might need to update your database with the command bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force. But first use always bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql to make sure you're not changing your database structure and losing data.

Comment: Could you please show your Comment entity class? I think the error could be in wrong annotation or missing field in the database

Comment: But be sure that $comments = $comRepo->findBy(array('filmId' => $id)); is correct way. Also, if you have right configuration(annotation) for the entity, you also can retrieve by $film->getComments();

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev I update my post for show my entity

Comment: @alexcm Yes i know i need to do that, but i'm afraid to breaks everythings :s

Comment: It shouldn't break things if you didn't have a big change in the entity attributes. That's why to dump-sql first, to make sure that everything is OK. But if you don't want to use it, can always manually change the structure at your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set up your ORM relations correctly, it should be as simple as:

```
$film = $repo->find($id);
$comments = $film->getComments();
```

You might be missing a mapping in Film.php.

Here's an XML example, should be easy enough to convert to annotations:

In film:

```
<one-to-many field="comments" target-entity="App\...\Comments" mapped-by="film"/>
```

In comments:

```
<many-to-one field="film" target-entity="App\...\Film" inversed-by="comments"/>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks u, i wanna try this. It does not matter if in my film entity I do not have a comment field ? so i don't have a getter for comments. should i add a variable and the appropriate getters / setters ?

Comment: Yes, you must add the comments property and a getter to the Film entity for it to work. The type would be `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I advise you to read more about the relations between [entities](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html).

Because, the current annotations says that you can have a lot of comments on many films. It's not right. One comment may belong to one film. One movie can have many comments.

Also, I want to note that, as far as I know, @JoinColumn should be in a child entity, that is, where the link to FK is contained.
Therefore, your entities should look like this:

Comment:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Film;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Film", inversedBy="comments")
     * Here we set property for our table and property of foreign table to map our comment to the right film
     * nullable, because comment couldn't be without film 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="film_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $film;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?User
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(?User $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getFilmId(): ?Film
    {
        return $this->filmId;
    }

    public function setFilmId(?Film $filmId): self
    {
        $this->filmId = $filmId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Film:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FilmRepository")
 */
class Film
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="film")
     */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function setComments(Collection $comments): Film
    {
        $this->comments = $comments;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

So, now, you can retrieve your comments via:

```
/**
     * @Route("/user/film/{id}", name="film")
     */
    public function film($id)
    {
        /** @var null|EntityManager $entityManager */
        $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        if (null == ($film = $entityManager->getRepository(Film::class)->find($id))){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Film not found');
        }

        $comments = $film->getComments();

        return $this->render('film/film.html.twig', [
            'film' => $film,
            'comments' => $comments
        ]);
    }
```